# How can I sort a list of directories alphabetically and get the first value that sorts after a specific string?

Tags: directory, backup, sort, timestamps

I have a directory full of backup folders, with names in the format yyyy-MM-dd--HH:mm:ss

If I enter a date in the same format, is there a way to get the first directory that sorts after it, and copy that folder to somewhere else?

e.g. If my list of backups looks like this:

```
2019-12-04--16:12:56
2019-12-09--13:36:53
2020-01-23--13:24:13
2020-01-23--13:47:03
```

and I enter `2020-01-05--00:00:00`, I want to restore `2020-01-23--13:24:13`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
for dir in ????-??-??--??:??:??/; do
    if [[ $dir > "2020-01-05--00:00:00" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$dir"

        # process "$dir" here

        break
    fi
done
```

The above script will loop through the directories in the current directory whose names matches the pattern `????-??-??--??:??:??`.

For each directory, it is compared to the string `2020-01-05--00:00:00`.  If it sorts after that string lexicographically, the name of the directory is printed and the loop is exited.

This works since the list resulting from a pathname expansion is sorted according to the current collating order (just like `ls` sorts the list by default).

To copy that directory to elsewhere, replace the comment with something like

```
rsync -av "$dir" /somewhere/elsewhere
```

The following is a script that takes the particular string from its first command line argument and does the same thing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ????-??-??--??:??:??/; do
    if [[ $dir > "$1" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$dir"

        # process "$dir" here

        break
    fi
done
```

Testing this with the directories that you list:

```
$ ls -l
total 10
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Jan 24 11:14 2019-12-04--16:12:56
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Jan 24 11:14 2019-12-09--13:36:53
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Jan 24 11:14 2020-01-23--13:24:13
drwxr-xr-x  2 myself  wheel  512 Jan 24 11:14 2020-01-23--13:47:03
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  wheel  119 Jan 24 11:23 script.sh
```

```
$ ./script.sh "2020-01-05--00:00:00"
2020-01-23--13:24:13/
```

Comment: Could you comment on why it is safe to assume that the glob expansion is performed in lexicographical sort order, and if possible add a link to the respective documentation?

Comment: @AdminBee - just look at bash man page, LC_COLLATE, "This variable determines the collation order used when sorting the results of pathname  expansion,  and determines the behavior of range expressions, equivalence classes, and collating sequences within pathname expansion and pattern matching."

Comment: @AdminBee The result of a pathname expansion is "sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale". https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03

Comment: @steve & Kusalananda thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks, the ???? syntax didn't seem to work for me so I matched the comparison string and the chosen directory against a regex in the end (which also conveniently rejects situations where the input datetime is after the latest datetime in the list)

Comment: @Tharwen Using `?` is standard syntax i filename globbing patterns. If it did not work, then your files have different names that are not matched by that pattern.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with

```
$ printf '%s\n' ????-??-??--??:??:?? | awk '$1 > "2020-01-05--00:00:00"{print;exit}'
2020-01-23--13:24:13
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
ref=2020-01-05--00:00:00
list=($ref *(DN/oN)) # list is ref + all directories unsorted
list=(${(o)list}) # sort the list (as per locale collation algorithm)
print -r -- ${list[$list[(ie)$ref] + 1]-none}
```

(where `$array[(ie)string]` expands to the array `i`ndex of the element that is `e`xactly `string`).

Answer (score 0):

`ls|sort|grep -A 1 2020-01-20|head -n 2|tail -n 1`

Comment: While this may work under certain conditions, it is highly disrecommended to parse the output of `ls`, see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score -2):

You may try

```
~$ ls -r | head -n 1
```

Comment: I think you might have misread the question